# Unit testing code that uses Task.Factory.StartNew().ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, task-parallel-library

so I have some code

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.listener.Start()).ContinueWith(
                    (task) =>
                        {
                            if (task.IsCompleted)
                            {
                                this.status = WorkerStatus.Started;
                                this.RaiseStatusChanged();
                                this.LogInformationMessage("Worker Started.");
                            }
                        });
```

When I am testing I am mocking all the dependant objects (namley this.listener.Start()). the problem is that the test finishes executing before ContinueWith can be called. When I debug it gets called fine due to the extra delay of me stepping through code.

so how can I - from the test code in a different assembly - ensure that the code is run before my test hits its asserts?

I could just use Thread.Sleep ... but this seems like a really hacky way of doing it.

I guess I am looking for the Task version of Thread.Join.

Comment: How does it finish, is there any error?

Comment: no error ... listener.start is mocked and it finishes .. i can verify that in debug mode. It is a timing problem

Comment: I would say it is rather a synchronisation problem, you need to get some feedback from the asynchronous method you call

Comment: yes I agree, a wrapper around task seems to be the answer. Its jsut that by that point I begin to feel like i'm implementing something very similar to what the threadpool can do already. Should of stuck with what i know lol.

Comment: For the benefit of others, see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/706553/Mocking-Task-Factory-StartNew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        var a = new Random().Next();
    }
}

public class MyUnitTest
{
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var target = new SomeClass();        
        target.Foo(); // What to assert, what is the result?..
    }
}
```

What is the value assigned to `a`? You cannot tell, unless the result is returned outside the method `Foo()` (as the return value, a public property, an event, etc.).

The process of "[coordinating the actions of threads for a predictable outcome](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)" is called [**Synchronization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

One of the easiest solutions in your case might be to return the instance of [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class and the use its [`Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) method:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1())
    .ContinueWith(() => Method2());
```

No need to wait for the first task, because [ContinueWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) creates a continuation that executes asynchronously **when the target Task completes** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)):

```
task.Wait();
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding his problem (or maybe I am?). His continuation task is apparently not executing because the initial task completed before the `ContinueWith` method can be called.

Comment: @davenewza No need to wait for the first task, because `ContinueWith()` creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes

Comment: I dont have access to the task instance from my test and would rather not write a wrapper around it just for that purpose (but maybe i have to).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy-yet-practical way of doing this. Ran into the same problem myself just now and Thread.Sleep(X) is by far the simplest (if not elegant) way of getting around the problem.

The only other solution that I considered is hiding the Task.Factory.StartNew() call behind an interface that you can mock from your test thus removing the actual execution of the task entirely in the test scenario (but still have an expectation that the interface method will be called. For example:

```
public interface ITaskWrapper
{
    void TaskMethod();
}
```

And your concrete implementation:

```
public class MyTask : ITaskWrapper
{
    public void TaskMethod()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
    }
}
```

Then just mock `ITaskWrapper` in your test method and set an expectation on `TaskMethod` being called.

Comment: yeah this is how i ended up dealing with the problem also. Was the only way i could see to enable any form of meaningful testing.

Comment: This is also the method used by the author here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/706553/Mocking-Task-Factory-StartNew

Answer (score 1):

If there's any way for you to be notified of when the processing has ended (can you add a handler for that StatusChanged event?), use a ManualResetEvent and wait on it with a reasonable timeout. If the timeout expired fail the test, otherwise go on and perform your assertions.

E.g.

```
var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
sut.StatusChanged += (s, e) => waitHandle.Set();

sut.DoStuff();

Assert.IsTrue(waitHandle.WaitOne(someTimeout), "timeout expired");
// do asserts here
```

Comment: I like the out of the box thinking. But doesn't help me with the general problem!

Comment: Help he understand. You were considering Thread.Sleep as an alternative. This works kind of like that, but it will continue as soon as the processing ended if you can be notified of it. The equivalent to Thread.Join is Task.Wait, but you've stated you don't expose a task in the method you're testing.

Comment: exactly. Maybe I have set up an impossible situation. In which case i will mark you as answer ;) ... The general answer right now seems to be write some kind of wrapper around the Task stuff so i can do what i need.  I am really checking that I am not about to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

The continuation task will still run regardless of whether the initial task completed before the `ContinueWith()` call or not.  I double checked this with the following:

```
// Task immediately exits
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });

Thread.Sleep(100);

// Continuation on already-completed task
task.ContinueWith(t => { MessageBox.Show("!"); });
```

Debug further.  Maybe your task is failing.

Comment: This is not what i am asking. Interesting that you can do this though i didnt realise you could add the continuation as an afterthought! My task cannot be failing because it is mocked and is doing nothing ... in effect I am executing the same thing as you but via the Moq proxy. Also the thread.sleep is exactly what i am trying to avoid doing. The problem is that tere is a delay between the task running and the continue running and this delay is longer than the rest of the test takes to run. I want to do an equivalent of what you can do with explicit threads and wait for finish and rejoin them.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with asynchronous processes during code under test that use Reactive Extensions, one approach is to use a TestScheduler. The TestScheduler can be moved forward in time, drained of all shceduled tasks, etc. So your code under test can take an IScheduler, which you provide a TestScheduler instance for. Then your test can manipulate time without needing to actually sleep, wait or synchronize. An improvement on this approach is [Lee Campbell's ISchedulerProvider](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#SchedulerDI) approach.

If you use Observable.Start instead of Task.Factory.StartNew in your code, you can then use your TestScheduler in the unit test to push through all the scheduled tasks.

For example, your code under test could look something like this:

```
//Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething())
//    .ContinueWith(t => DoSomethingElse())
Observable.Start(() => DoSomething(), schedulerProvider.ThreadPool)
          .ToTask()
          .ContinueWith(t => DoSomethingElse())
```

and in your unit test:

```
// ... test code to execute the code under test

// run the tasks on the ThreadPool scheduler
testSchedulers.ThreadPool.Start();

// assertion code can now run
```

Comment: this looks interesting, when I run into this problem again I will remember to come back to this answer :D I did something similar.

Comment: There is also a similar approach in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17844870/114200 except that it uses Task schedulers and involves implementing your own scheduler. I prefer the approach above, but if you're not already using Rx then the Task Scheduler approach may be of interest as well.