# Wait until all Task finish in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, synchronization, task

I have this class I want to unit test:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Bar();
    }

    private void Bar()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Do something that takes some time (e.g. an HTTP request)
        });
    }
}
```

And this is how my unit test looks like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFoo()
{
    // Arrange
    var obj = new SomeClass();

    // Act
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();

    // Assert
    /* I need something to wait on all tasks to finish */
    Assert.IsTrue(...);
}
```

So, I need to make the unit test thread wait until all tasks started in the `Bar` method have finished their job before starting my assertions.

**IMPORTANT**: I cannot change `SomeClass`

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Unfortunately, your design is broken. You shouldn't be spawning off new tasks without returning something for the caller to wait on. This is particularly problematic since the threads of the managed thread pool (on which your tasks execute) are marked as background threads, meaning that your tasks may be aborted before completion should the foreground threads of your application terminate.

Comment: I know that, but unfortunately I cannot change it and the above sample is just a simplification of the much complex situation I'm facing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to define your own task scheduler in such a way that would allow you to keep track of the completion of your nested tasks. For example, you could define a scheduler that executes tasks synchronously, as below:

```
class SynchronousTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool wasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Subsequently, create an instance of this synchronous task scheduler, and use it to execute a root task which, in turn, spawns all of your "hidden" tasks. Since nested tasks inherit the current task scheduler from their parent, all your inner tasks will also get run on our synchronous scheduler, implying that our outermost `StartNew` call will only return when all tasks complete.

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = new SynchronousTaskScheduler();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Arrange
    var obj = new SomeClass();

    // Act
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();
}, 
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    scheduler);

// Assert
/* I need something to wait on all tasks to finish */
Assert.IsTrue(...);
```

A downside to this approach is that you will lose all concurrency from your tasks; however, you could fix this by enhancing the custom scheduler to one which is concurrent but still allows you to track executing tasks.

Comment: This answer probably saved me hours of my life. So much win in finding out stuff beforehand. Thanks!

Comment: i cannot get your SynchronousTaskScheduler working in a particular cast, i posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482048/currentthreadtaskscheduler-does-not-finish-synchronous

Comment: It will not work if your hidden tasks are started with `Task.Run` and not `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: @JustAMartin: Correct. `Task.Run` is equivalent to `Task.Factory.StartNew(…, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default)`, so nested tasks wouldn't inherit the current task scheduler from their parent.

Answer (score 6):

```
Task.WaitAll(the, list, of, task, objects, you, need, to, wait, on);
```

If it's a `void async` method then you can't do it. The design is broken. They're only for fire and forget.

Comment: Unfortunately for @Toto the task objects are not available in his unit test

Comment: There is no async involved in the OP Question.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are allowed to make this change but I got it to work doing this:

```
namespace ParallelProgramming.Playground
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public Task Foo()
        {
            return Bar();
        }

        private static Task Bar()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I fired off. Thread ID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    return true; //or whatever else you want.
                });
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class StackOverflow
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFoo()
        {
            // Arrange
            var obj = new SomeClass();

            var results = new ConcurrentBag<Task>(); 
            var waitForMe = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Act
                    results.Add(obj.Foo());
                    results.Add(obj.Foo());
                    results.Add(obj.Foo());

                    return true;
                });


            Task.WaitAll(waitForMe);

            // Assert
            /* I need something to wait on all tasks to finish */
            Assert.IsTrue(waitForMe.Result);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, results.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually if you are using `Thread` with TPL it's becomes a legacy code. So it's not so necessary.

Comment: The thread was not suggested for an answer. I was using it to give the methods some load time since it did nothing but Console.Writeline.

Comment: I've read in Stephen Cleary book that if you use Thread inside a TPL application, it's already became a `Legacy Code`. Just thought it's worth mentioning down, mate.

Comment: @IamStalker I agree with you it's a very good note. I am just hoping that someone looking at the example can figure out that you wouldn't have that there. :)  

But again yes very great to point out.

Comment: You can also call `waitForMe.Wait()` rather than WaitAll, which I think is a bit tidier.