# CurrentThreadTaskScheduler does not finish Synchronous

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, async-await

I try to write a Unit-Test for a View Model, but i got stuck when trying to verify a ICommand calls a asynchronous method twice.

i use Moq for my dependencies.
I set up the async Method like this.

```
this.communicationServiceFake
     .Setup(x => x.WriteParameterAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
     .ReturnsAsyncIncomplete();
```

The Extension ReturnsAsyncIncomplete does not return instantly at the await keyword, basically something like that found here: [Async/Await and code coverage](http://bernhard-richter.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/asyncawait-and-code-coverage.html)

I use a own TaskSheduler to ensure that the Methods are compete before the Task.Factory.StartNew returns.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => viewModel.Command.Execute(null), 
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, new CurrentThreadTaskScheduler ());
```

Basically the CurrentThreadTaskScheduler comes from here: [Wait until all Task finish in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844182/wait-until-all-task-finish-in-unit-test) and does look like this:

```
public class CurrentThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool wasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

the Command does call the following code:

```
await this.communicationService.WriteParameterAsync("Parameter1", true);
await this.communicationService.WriteParameterAsync("Parameter2", true);
```

Then the verification:

```
  this.communicationServiceFake
       .Verify(t => t.WriteParameterAsync("Parameter1", true), Times.Once);
  this.communicationServiceFake
       .Verify(t => t.WriteParameterAsync("Parameter2", true), Times.Once);
```

sometimes it says the 2nd call did not happen.
If i replace my Task.Factory.StartNew with a ThreadSleep to ensure everything finished, all works fine even thought it does note seem right to delay my unit tests unnecessarily.

Why does my CurrentThreadTaskScheduler allow the Task.Factory.StartNew to return before my Command.Execute finished?

Comment: I can't seem to grasp why you need to use `StartNew` at all?

Comment: The Command.Execute has some fire and forget tasks in the background that are not finished if i just use viewModel.Command.Execute, this is a attempt to await these fire and forget tasks with a customer task scheduler. Sadly it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `GetIncompleteTask` extension method in [the linked blog post](http://bernhard-richter.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/asyncawait-and-code-coverage.html) uses `Task.Run`, hence introducing another thread (and a race condition).

The `CurrentThreadTaskScheduler` will only work for `async void` methods if all tasks are already completed, which is exactly what you're *avoiding* with `ReturnsAsyncIncomplete`.

Here's what's happening:

1. `Execute` runs in `CurrentThreadTaskScheduler`. It `await`s an incomplete task that is running on the threadpool. At this point, the `StartNew` task is complete.
2. The thread pool thread finishes the incomplete task, and executes its continuations on the *current* thread (the thread pool thread).

What you're trying to do is unit test an `async void` method with full coverage (i.e., asynchronously). This is certainly not easy.

**Recommended solution**

Use some form of an `async`-aware `ICommand` such as the ones I describe in [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). Then you can just use `await viewModel.Command.ExecuteAsync(null)` in your unit test and not mess around with custom task schedulers at all.

Also, the asynchronous mocking can really be simplified; there's no need for a custom awaiter because the .NET framework already has one: `Task.Yield`. So you can replace all that code with just a single extension method (untested):

```
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsIncompleteAsync<TMock, TResult>(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, TResult value) where TMock : class
{
  return mock.Returns(async () =>
  {
    await Task.Yield();
    return value;
  });
}
```

**Keeping async void**

If you really want to keep your existing `ICommand` implementations, and want to unit test `async void` methods, *and* want full code coverage, then you really need a custom `SynchronizationContext` instead of a custom `TaskScheduler`. The easiest way to do this is to install my [AsyncEx NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) and use `AsyncContext`:

```
// Blocks the current thread until all continuations have completed.
AsyncContext.Run(() => viewModel.Command.Execute(null));
```

Also, I recommend you use the `Task.Yield` approach described above instead of the custom-awaitable-on-a-thread-pool.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, If i got it right the IAsyncCommand does only provide a solution if i can change the type in my view model to IAsyncCommand otherwise i am still stuck at my unit tests using ICommand.Execute which is implemented as async void again, right?